# How do you get the warm doublet?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

I've just started playing Legend of the Zelda BOTW, but I can't get the paraglider because I need four spirit orbs, which means I need to complete 4 shrines. I've found all 4 but could only get to and complete 2, the other 2 couldn't be reached because they were blocked by dangerously cold lands.The only way to get past the place was the warm doublet. As far as I know, the only way to get the warm doublet is from the old man. However, there seems to be no way to get the warm doublet from the old man. He didn't give me a quest or anything like that. How do you get the warm doublet?

Comment: Please do not answer in comments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are [3 ways to get it from the Old Man](http://Once%20you%20use%20one%20method,%20you%20can%27t%20use%20the%20others):

- Read the diary in his hut on the Great Plateau, then cook a meal using a spicy pepper, meat and a Hyrule bass. Show him the meal, and he will give you the warm doublet.
- Climb to the top of Mount Hylia on the Great Plateau (before you complete the trials on the Great Plateau). He will appear and give you the warm doublet as a reward.
- After completing the Great Plateau, he will leave a warm doublet in his hut.

Once you obtain it from one method, you can't obtain it from the other 2. But you can still buy it from Hateno Village later in the game for 80 rupees.

Comment: 80 rupees? Thats cheap!

Comment: Easter egg: the rock that the Old Man stands by on Mount Hylia is his grave. It's theorized that he dug his own grave, as the Plateau's entrance was blocked off during the Calamity, and there wasn't anybody else already on the Plateau

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to have the warm doublet to travel through the cold areas. Hint: try cooking.

> The Spicy Meat and Seafood Fry dish will give you low-level cold resistance.

A number of sites, including [shacknews](https://www.shacknews.com/article/99322/how-to-get-the-warm-doublet-breath-of-the-wild) and [gamesradar](https://www.gamesradar.com/legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild-old-man-locations-warm-doublet-recipe-paraglider-shrine/3/), have guides on this topic. It's also possible to just buy the Warm Doublet, after you leave The Great Plateau.

Comment: First of all, I asked for a way to get the warm doublet for constant cold resistanse, not food cause there is no way for me to know if I have enough food.

Comment: @Bloonchipper If you look at either of the links I provided, or the answer that you accepted above, you'll see that cooking is still basically a requirement to get the warm doublet.

Comment: I can't use the links. They don't work for me. Although your answer does make sense for the "need to cook to get warm doublet" part.